# Angular 2 Router + angular-cli

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to follow the Angular 2 doc for an in-depht understanding of routing with Angular 2 : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-config

When I try to redirect as explained to a default page, the typescript compiler send me this error :

```
    Type '{ path: string; redirectTo: string; pathMatch: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pathMatch' does not exist in type 'Route'.
```

Here is my code :

```
export const CrisisCenterRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/crisis-center',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'crisis-center',
    component: CrisisCenterComponent,
    children: [
      { path: ':id',  component: CrisisDetailComponent },
      { path: '',     component: CrisisListComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: CrisisAdminComponent
  },
];
```

I can't find any explanation for this obvious issue. The code compiles when I delete the 'pathMatch' property.

Thanks a lot for your explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on a bit older version. Use `@angular/router` version should be `3.0.0-beta.2`

Comment: Thanks a lot I was going crazy ;)

Comment: Seriously... updated from 3.0.0-alpha.8 to beta.2 ... UGH (intellij generated template)